# JavaScript "document.getElementById().innerHTML" waits in loop

Tags: javascript, sleep, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have a JS program which cycles through a list of words and sets the text of the

```html
<span id="changing"></span>
```

To the current item in the list. Here's my code:

```
const words = [
  "Amazing",
  "Simple",
  "Powerful",
  "Extensible",
  "Fast",
  "Lightweight",
  "Integrated",
  "Incredible",
];

let num = 0;

function infinite() {
  while (num < 1) {
    words.forEach((item) => {
      document.getElementById("changing").innerHTML = item;
    });
  }
}
```

How can I wait 1 second each time it changes the word? (also, this doesn't seem to do anything, so if you could help with that, that would be absolutely amazing)

Comment: Use setInterval

Comment: infinite is going to block your browser

Comment: using setTimeout will fix both of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in javascript function called `setInterval()` which infinitely does a function in intervals of `n` in milliseconds. Applying this to your situation:

```js
const words = ["Amazing", "Simple", "Powerful", "Extensible", "Fast", "Lightweight", "Integrated", "Incredible"];

var index = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("changing").textContent = words[index];
  index = (index+1) % words.length;// If index becomes the last element, it will then go to the first element, making a loop
}, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 s
```

```html
<span id="changing"></span>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But do you know if there's any way to use a CSS `transition all ease-in-out` to make this look even better?

Comment: It's definitely possible but I'm not sure transition is what you should use but rather `animation`. What kind of animation are you looking for between the texts?

Comment: Just a simple fade effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a little bit of recursion, and using the `setTimeout` function.

```
const words = ["Amazing", "Simple", "Powerful", "Extensible", "Fast", "Lightweight", "Integrated", "Incredible"];
function infinite(index) {
   if (index === words.length) {
       index = 0;
   }

   document.getElementById("changing").innerHTML = words[index];
   setTimeout(() => infinite(index + 1), 1000);
}

infinite(0);
```

Or you could use `setInterval` to acheive the same thing

```
const words = ["Amazing", "Simple", "Powerful", "Extensible", "Fast", "Lightweight", "Integrated", "Incredible"];

let index = 0;

function infinite() {
   if (index >= words.length) {
       index = 0;
   }

   document.getElementById("changing").innerHTML = words[index];
   index++;
}

setInterval(infinite, 1000);
```

With that specific implementation however, the `index` variable would be open to change from anything else in that scope. The `setTimeout` method encapsulates the index value so that it can't be changed externally.